# Java Incompatible Types: Expected Number; Found Integer

Tags: java, inheritance, hashmap, polymorphism

I have a parent class that has a `HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, Number>` as an instance variable. This class has various children that need to use different types of numbers (Integer, Double) as the value type for this map. When I try to initialize the map in the constructor of a subclass, I get the following error:

```
Incompatible types.
Required: HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, java.lang.Number>

Found: HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>,java.lang.Integer>
```

Since Integer extends Number, shouldn't this work due to polymorphism?

Comment: The answer to your last question is: no, because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```java
HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, ? extends Number>
```

instead of:

```java
HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, Number>
```

to declare the super type of:

```java
HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, ANYTHING_EXTENDING_NUMBER>
```

Therefore:

```java
HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, ? extends Number> hashMap1 = 
  new HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, Integer>(); //Compiles OK.
HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, Number> hashMap2 = 
  new HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, Integer>(); //Does not compile.
```

Generally, remember, that in Generics, `T<Parent>` is not a super type of `T<Child>`; rather `T<? extends Parent>` is a super type of `T<Child>`.

One thing to bear in mind is the [Capture Problem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html), that is, you will not be able to add the elements of the subtype you use as a generic type argument.

For example, this:

```java
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
Integer integer = new Integer(5);

HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, ? extends Number> hashMap
    = new HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, Integer>();
```

will work fine;

however, this afterwards:

```java
hashMap.put(arrayList, new Integer(3)); //Does not work.
```

will not work.

Have a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html) section from Java tutorial.

Comment: So how do I go about putting integers into a ```Map<ArrayList<Integer>, Integer>```? When I do .put(list, 10). I get a similar type error.

Comment: You can not, because of the [capture problem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html). You can declare a variable with the super generic type (given above) and assign to that variable any child generic type, but you cannot add the value of subtype of the type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a `Map<List<Integer>, Number>` instead should allow compilation to continue.

The reason this doesn't work is because `Map<List<Integer>, Number>` is not a sub-type of `Map<List<Integer>, Integer>`. One way to understand this is by recognizing that a Double is a Number but not an Integer. As such, adding a double to the first map will succeed but will fail for the second map.

As an aside, it is strange to have the Map key be a list. Should this be flipped?

Comment: That makes sense. The key is a list that has a fitness value, the value of the Map. I'm using this for a genetic algorithm.

Comment: It is generally recommended to keep the map key immutable. If the List or elements in the list can be modified, you may see strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using map definition `HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, ? extends Number>` like this then inheritance `Integer extends Number` can be applied successfully:

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> imap = new HashMap<>(Map.of(1, 1, 2, 20, 3, 300));
print(imap); // ok
Map<Integer, Double> dmap = new HashMap<>(Map.of(1, 1.25, 5, 10.0, 10, 300.0));
print(dmap); // ok

Map<Integer, ? extends Number> nemap = imap;  // that's ok
imap.put(4, 400); // ok
// nemap.put(5, 500); // fails: required type: capture ? extends Number

Map<Integer, ? super Number> nsmap = new HashMap<>();
nsmap.put(5, 500);  // ok!
nsmap.put(1, 10.0);  // ok too
print(nsmap); // succeeds

System.out.println(nemap);
nemap = dmap;
System.out.println(nemap);
// -----

private static void print(Map<Integer, ? extends Number> map) {
    map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```